# Проверка сигнатуры на golang сервере

Tags: golang, backend

Со стороннего апи приходит пост запрос, в котором есть body. Среди прочих параметров есть поле checksum, которое содержит хэш сумму. Задача проверить хэш сумму, для того чтобы удостовериться в подлинности сообщения. Для этого нужно:
-Взять все поля тела запроса и сгенерировать вот такую строку(параметр checksum откидывается):
`"param1;value1;param2;value2;paramN;valueN;"`
(ключи/значения разделены ";", при этом все параметры предварительно должны быть отсортированные в алфавитном порядке).
-Все действия которые выполняются дальше не вызывают затруднений, трудность в составлении этой строки, причем используя эффективный алгоритм

Comment: В каком формате у вас данные в теле? Есть ли повторяющиеся имена параметров?

Comment: Формат json, повторных нет. И в строке параметры должны быть именно в том виде, в котором пришли в json

Comment: И есть два варианта получения данных со стороннего апи, через Post в body и через Get в query params

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою задачу, вот таким образом:

```
func CreateSignatureString(request Request) string {
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(request)

    stringData := string(jsonData[1 : len(jsonData)-1])
    stringData = strings.ReplaceAll(stringData, "\"", "")
    stringData = strings.ReplaceAll(stringData, ":", ";")

    sliceString := strings.Split(stringData, ",")

    sort.Strings(sliceString)

    newSlice := make([]string, 0, len(sliceString)-2)

    for _, val := range sliceString {
        if strings.HasPrefix(val, "checksum") || strings.HasPrefix(val, "sign_alias") {
            continue
        }
        newSlice = append(newSlice, val)
    }

    resultString := strings.Join(newSlice, ";") + ";"

    return resultString
}
```

Request в данном примере, это стуктурный тип, в который парсился body запроса.